# Reading files - which approach is testable?

Tags: java, file

In the question below, I have to read a text file and do some "processing". There are many approaches in tutorials to read files. But, I would like to test my code without even reading a file first. Instead, I would like to read a file with some class which has utility methods to inject lines into it instead of actually reading them from a file. Which approach to file reading allows me to do that ?

**Pseudocode for what I need :**

```
TestableFileReader.injectLine("1.0, 2.0, 3.0, -1100");//Garbage data in line.
String line = TestableFileReader.readNextLine();
doProcessing(line);
```

> Write a method public ArrayList readValues(String filename)
>   throws ... that reads a file containing floating-point numbers. Throw
>   appropriate exceptions if the file could not be opened or if some of
>   the inputs are not floating-point numbers.

Comment: Pass an `Reader` to your method. This could be a `FileReader`; but it could also be a `StringReader`, which makes it easy to test without actually involving files.

Comment: @AndyTurner - feel free to write it as an answer.

Comment: Why not just make a simple text file in whatever simple text editor you environment has?

Comment: @NomadMaker - I don't want to read a file every time I run a test for extracting numbers from a String (regardless of where that string came from - file, database etc.). The file reading code will work fine as long as you provide it a file.

Comment: It's no more difficult to read a simple text file than it is to read a string, as long as you read the same file each time.

Comment: @NomadMaker - Do you see any problems in doing it with a string instead of file for testing ?

Comment: Only that you will need to test with files to make sure you've got everything,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code to do it. The code can be refactored to make it easy to automate the testing with various values of String line instead of hard coding a fixed string as shown below.

```
//Method signature from book.
public static List<Double> readValues(String filename) throws IOException {
    ArrayList<Double> values = new ArrayList<>();
    String line = "1.0, 2.5, 3, -5, A, ë";
    Reader reader = new StringReader(line); //new FileReader(filename);

    //Is there a shorter way to do this, i.e without try-catch ?
    Function<String, Boolean> isStringDouble = (string -> {
        try{
            return Double.valueOf(string) instanceof Double;
        }catch (NumberFormatException ex){
            return false;
        }
    });


    //Decorate reader with BufferedReader to get readLine functionality.
    try(BufferedReader bReader = new BufferedReader(reader)){
        while ((line = bReader.readLine()) != null) {
             Map<Boolean, List<String>> lineParts = Arrays
                     .stream(line.split(","))
                     .map(v -> v.trim())
                     .collect( Collectors.groupingBy(v -> isStringDouble.apply(v)) );

             lineParts.forEach( ( (k, v) -> System.out.printf("are doubles = %s : %s\n", k, v)  ) );
        }
    }
    return values;
}

public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
    readValues("hello");
}
```